# How could I get device id in react js?

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, npm, package

As I tryied react-native-device-info in my mobile app but now I want to get the device ID in my web app. How could I get the device ID in React js for my web app. Is there any NPM or any other alternative?

Thanks In Advance

Did not got any node package related to this.

Answer (score 2):

In a web app, you cannot directly obtain a device ID due to privacy and security considerations enforced by web browsers. Unlike mobile apps, which may have access to device-specific information through platform-specific APIs, web browsers restrict access to such data to protect user privacy and prevent potential misuse.
Browsers are designed to provide a secure and controlled environment for users, and this includes limiting the information that websites and web applications can access. While some limited device information might be available through APIs like navigator.userAgent or navigator.platform, these details are not sufficient for generating a unique device ID in the same way that you can achieve in a mobile app using tools like react-native-device-info. 
But you can make use of the [MediaDeviceInfo](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MediaDeviceInfo/deviceId) interface to get a unique identifier for media input devices like cameras and microphones within the context of a web application. It represents a browser-generated identifier that is unique to the origin of the application. This property allows you to differentiate between different devices, but it's not the same as a device ID specific to the physical hardware.

Answer (score 0):

In a web browser environment, it's not possible to directly access a unique device identifier due to privacy and security concerns. Browsers intentionally restrict access to such identifiers to prevent tracking and maintain user privacy. However, you can use alternative methods to uniquely identify devices within your application.

```
const userAgent = window.navigator.userAgent;
const platform = window.navigator.platform;
const randomString = Math.random().toString(20).substring(2, 14) + Math.random().toString(20).substring(2, 14);

const deviceID = `${userAgent}-${platform}-${randomString}`;
console.log(deviceID)
```